# How to inherit css from grandparent tag?

Tags: css

I am having a two level nested div and I want to apply the div holding a class "c" with the same width of div with class a. If it is parent then I guess inherit will do the job. But what to be done in this case?

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
     <div class="c">

     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.a{
 width:600px;
}
.b{
width:80%;
}
.c{
//needs to inherit width property set for class a without directly mentioning it as 600px
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this in pure CSS, by default the child element never inherits the `width`, you need to specify it, yes, by default it will span 100% if you use a block level element like a `div` or `p` tag but inorder to <s>inherit</s>(re use) the property of grand parent you can use CSS pre processors like LESS or SASS..

So if you want to do this in SASS we can do something like

```
.a {
  width: 600px;
}

.b {
  width: 80%;
}

.c {
  @extend .a;
  //This is still not an inheritance, you are simply pulling in all the
  //properties defined in .a to this class
}
```

So here it will pick all the properties from `.a` to `.c`. But here's a catch, when you use `.` notation in SASS, it will literally print the `.a` block as well, so if you want to only use it for `@extend` purpose, you can write this selector instead

```
%a {
  width: 600px;
}

.c {
  @extend %a;
}
```

Here SASS won't print `.a` anymore but only `.c`.You can refer the official docs for more over [SASS @extend](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend)

You can also define variables in SASS so defining one with `$base-width: 600px;` and re using it across can make sense as well. If you still want to stick with traditional CSS than I would recommend you declaring multiple classes just like Manoj suggested but I would not do this as if you are declaring any properties in `.a` and same in `.c` things will start getting messy.

Comment: i'd recommend using a variable: `$width: 600px;` and `.c { width: $width; }` over `@extend` as the latter can have unexpected and tricky consequences

Comment: I was going to write it in my own answer but I think it'll probably just get lost

Comment: xD I wrote that first and I removed it, so I thought to add it again just because it's also one of the best way to handle such stuff

Comment: `@extends` has caused me multiple headaches which is why I'm wary - I now only use it within modules in a BEM / OOCSS type set up, preferably within the same sass file

Comment: Using SASS or LESS has other benefits, too.

Answer (score 4):

You can add multiple classes to the grandchild div to `include` the properties of a to c.

Also setting 80% for `.b` will result in 80% of 600px = `480px` for `.c` You need to modify it to 100%.

```css
.a {
  width: 600px;
}
.b {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="a c">
      I am 600px wide.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not class inheritance .. `c` will never inherit `a`

Comment: Oops, I meant to `include` instead of `inherit`

Answer (score 2):

Below is a possibility and as such could be useful, but is not recommended as the best way for most cases. It reminds me of the problems with `em` units.

Using a pre-processor with variables is a better way, though it isn't exactly inheritance nor is it pure css.

```
.a {
    width:600px;
}
.b {
    width:80%;
}
.c {
    width: 125%;
}
```

Where the `.c { width }` is `100 / .b { width } * 100`, or in the example 125%.

See an [example here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6kpydsa0/3/)

You are still inheriting from the parent, but the parent in turn inherits from the grandparent.