# CSS inheriting from a specific element

Tags: html, css

In `CSS` is it possible to use the `inherit` property  to inherit from a specific element?

For example is there `CSS` syntax which could let this `<p>` inherit from container1 instead of container2? Assuming there isn't cause searched for quite a while to find this but I hope you can prove me wrong.

```css
.container1{
 color: blue
}

.container2{
 color: green
}

.p {
 color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
 <div class="container2">
  <p>
    foo
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inherit css from grandparent tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218212/how-to-inherit-css-from-grandparent-tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent an element from inheriting from its parent, you could explicitly exclude it from its parent's CSS using the **[:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)** pseudo-class:

For example:

```
.container2 :not(p) {
  color: green;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
.container1 {
  color: blue;
}

.container2 :not(p) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="container2">
    <p>
      Feeling rather blue today.
    </p>
    <span>
      It's not easy being green.
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```